# NodeJS not recognized under Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows-10

I am using the LTS version of NodeJS. The problem started with version `node-v16.18.0-x64` and did continue with `node-v18.12.0-x64`.

What I am doing:
Developing Playwright test. I ran the test and NodeJS was working. After one minute, I rerun the test and NodeJS is no longer recognized in my OS.
The issue appears when I am using Cypress, so I think the issue is not related to the technology that I am using.

I checked the environment variable: It is there.

The workaround I am doing is to uninstall the NodeJS from the control panel and install it again. There is an option to repair the NodeJS installation. But when I try to use it, I receive an error message that the NodeJS is not installed on this OS.

Comment: What do you mean by "*NodeJS is no longer recognized in my OS*" Please post the **exact** steps you are executing and the **exact** error message you get. Programs don't mysteriously vanish when installed. The only thing I can think of is, that something is messing around with your environment variables (especially the `PATH`). Do you use `nvm` or something similar?

Comment: @derpirscher 
Error message: 
`'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. `
Here are pictures of environment variables before the crash and after.
before - [link](https://ibb.co/r3t2dvW)
after - [link](https://ibb.co/NY0ByDW)
Yes, I am using nvm, but the problem was available before I started using nvm.

I cannot provide the exact steps because I cannot isolate the problem. For example - I executed one test. After one minute, I tried to run the same test (with minor refactoring in the code) and the Nodejs were no longer recognisable.